# Convert XmlElement Object to PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell

I am working on a tool and this tool will gather data from the customer environment and will then data these gathered data into PSCustomObjects then will dump the Object into an XML file using the Export-Clixml.

The Problem is in some Objects the Export-Clixml will dump the data and when using the Import-Clixml these object will have the value of #text instead the real value.

For example:

I am getting the Certificate info from the NSX Manager using PowerNsx and then add it to a PSCustomObject

```
$NsxManagerCertificate = Get-NsxManagerCertificate
$TestObject = [PSCustomObject] {
     NsxManagerCertificate = $NsxManagerCertificate
}
Export-Clixml -InputObject $TestObject -Path E:\TestDump.xml
```

If I checked the variables output you will get the real data:

```
C:\Users\Administrator> $NsxManagerCertificate


subjectCn            : CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss
issuerCn             : CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss
version              : 3
serialNumber         : 49044a14
signatureAlgo        : SHA256WITHRSA
signature            : 0b 5d c7 cb ab 58 0d 9a ff 03 e9 0a e5 91 61 64 16 22 c7 c2 21 28 50 f2 ad 02 21 e9 48 4e f6 72 d3 91 f1 19 3e 3e 25 3a fd 28 ab 81 e2 6c d1 35 51 dc 13 c4 22 f3 cb 53 db 6d c5 0c fe ff 6b 0b cd fc 17 d2 d5 bd d0 b8 13 e2 
                       53 e7 2b 1e 8a 84 ee 54 f4 dc b3 7d 1a 70 4b 71 12 42 6b 2c b5 1c 65 85 94 9d f5 00 7c 28 0f 6f 5b 15 b4 fe 67 e2 fa 4c 10 6c 31 a4 4a df 48 f2 c1 a1 66 e5 d2 0a 80 3e f4 02 c3 75 95 4c e0 d8 5b 90 74 9a 85 56 b4 f2 9e 2b 
                       c3 c7 f4 71 fa 43 b2 c2 1e 65 a6 0b 8b eb fc 39 77 bd 04 39 b4 99 64 81 d5 0d 81 88 a9 33 63 72 9f a4 b3 d7 c5 33 97 14 d5 be 3f 8e a9 de fd 0f 1c 3d 63 fd 0c ff e2 12 03 59 53 f1 a5 96 cb a6 03 23 4b ef 71 38 0e 96 fb 85 
                       4d 4c a8 8b 48 50 a6 e0 ff c6 f9 25 b5 8f d4 d2 0c 82 4c ff 9f e3 ef 9a e9 44 57 c5 3c 06 b8 b5 f9 2e
notBefore            : 1527008785000
notAfter             : 1842368785000
issuer               : CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
subject              : CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
publicKeyAlgo        : RSA
publicKeyLength      : 2048
rsaPublicKeyModulus  : 00 a5 7d 07 71 38 f5 39 fd 64 61 15 4a a6 ec 2a 51 d6 1b 49 08 6b 37 74 ae 8e 5e 21 db a5 48 73 e1 45 5b 02 5c 60 0c 9c 49 77 45 a4 43 f9 2b 05 a8 02 3b cb e7 17 89 18 79 38 5b a0 1d 77 3b c3 90 3d 39 8c 5e 25 90 80 d0 a0 
                       df f1 32 52 4c 46 8b 86 1f 67 5b 1a ee 56 3e d0 bf cc 45 5d 7a b8 f7 65 d0 4b 92 94 9f 1f 22 0d ae a6 d2 cb e6 00 92 f6 41 1b 52 4b 1d ba dc 24 04 e3 f5 2c c5 26 f0 d0 2c 02 b4 6b c2 f0 12 e7 20 c5 fe 4f d2 8f 12 8d 2d 2c 
                       3e 8a cb 63 f7 d9 37 0c fd 43 53 e3 14 cd 51 b5 68 0d e7 59 ad a3 8e 28 53 72 d1 97 65 f2 bf fb 6c 78 63 d8 57 fe 8f 6b 89 53 ac a2 0c 0d 83 bd be d5 14 7b 4c cf 15 22 60 17 1e 1f f7 28 7f 64 ac 28 a7 26 d3 bc c7 5a c0 42 
                       e6 34 00 57 62 99 6a 0c 4c 54 a4 6e b7 b8 73 43 1d 65 f7 b8 cd fc 99 75 8c 49 f1 0f 72 70 1b 4c 47 0e 7b
rsaPublicKeyExponent : 10001
sha1Hash             : 05:69:31:14:c9:41:0d:30:d6:52:e6:83:e8:6a:56:ad:1e:84:a5:37
md5Hash              : 1c:cb:26:9b:2b:b5:09:6f:b1:cd:91:00:c3:f7:34:9f
isCa                 : false
isValid              : true


C:\Users\Administrator> $TestObject.NsxManagerCertificate


subjectCn            : CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss
issuerCn             : CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss
version              : 3
serialNumber         : 49044a14
signatureAlgo        : SHA256WITHRSA
signature            : 0b 5d c7 cb ab 58 0d 9a ff 03 e9 0a e5 91 61 64 16 22 c7 c2 21 28 50 f2 ad 02 21 e9 48 4e f6 72 d3 91 f1 19 3e 3e 25 3a fd 28 ab 81 e2 6c d1 35 51 dc 13 c4 22 f3 cb 53 db 6d c5 0c fe ff 6b 0b cd fc 17 d2 d5 bd d0 b8 13 e2 
                       53 e7 2b 1e 8a 84 ee 54 f4 dc b3 7d 1a 70 4b 71 12 42 6b 2c b5 1c 65 85 94 9d f5 00 7c 28 0f 6f 5b 15 b4 fe 67 e2 fa 4c 10 6c 31 a4 4a df 48 f2 c1 a1 66 e5 d2 0a 80 3e f4 02 c3 75 95 4c e0 d8 5b 90 74 9a 85 56 b4 f2 9e 2b 
                       c3 c7 f4 71 fa 43 b2 c2 1e 65 a6 0b 8b eb fc 39 77 bd 04 39 b4 99 64 81 d5 0d 81 88 a9 33 63 72 9f a4 b3 d7 c5 33 97 14 d5 be 3f 8e a9 de fd 0f 1c 3d 63 fd 0c ff e2 12 03 59 53 f1 a5 96 cb a6 03 23 4b ef 71 38 0e 96 fb 85 
                       4d 4c a8 8b 48 50 a6 e0 ff c6 f9 25 b5 8f d4 d2 0c 82 4c ff 9f e3 ef 9a e9 44 57 c5 3c 06 b8 b5 f9 2e
notBefore            : 1527008785000
notAfter             : 1842368785000
issuer               : CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
subject              : CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
publicKeyAlgo        : RSA
publicKeyLength      : 2048
rsaPublicKeyModulus  : 00 a5 7d 07 71 38 f5 39 fd 64 61 15 4a a6 ec 2a 51 d6 1b 49 08 6b 37 74 ae 8e 5e 21 db a5 48 73 e1 45 5b 02 5c 60 0c 9c 49 77 45 a4 43 f9 2b 05 a8 02 3b cb e7 17 89 18 79 38 5b a0 1d 77 3b c3 90 3d 39 8c 5e 25 90 80 d0 a0 
                       df f1 32 52 4c 46 8b 86 1f 67 5b 1a ee 56 3e d0 bf cc 45 5d 7a b8 f7 65 d0 4b 92 94 9f 1f 22 0d ae a6 d2 cb e6 00 92 f6 41 1b 52 4b 1d ba dc 24 04 e3 f5 2c c5 26 f0 d0 2c 02 b4 6b c2 f0 12 e7 20 c5 fe 4f d2 8f 12 8d 2d 2c 
                       3e 8a cb 63 f7 d9 37 0c fd 43 53 e3 14 cd 51 b5 68 0d e7 59 ad a3 8e 28 53 72 d1 97 65 f2 bf fb 6c 78 63 d8 57 fe 8f 6b 89 53 ac a2 0c 0d 83 bd be d5 14 7b 4c cf 15 22 60 17 1e 1f f7 28 7f 64 ac 28 a7 26 d3 bc c7 5a c0 42 
                       e6 34 00 57 62 99 6a 0c 4c 54 a4 6e b7 b8 73 43 1d 65 f7 b8 cd fc 99 75 8c 49 f1 0f 72 70 1b 4c 47 0e 7b
rsaPublicKeyExponent : 10001
sha1Hash             : 05:69:31:14:c9:41:0d:30:d6:52:e6:83:e8:6a:56:ad:1e:84:a5:37
md5Hash              : 1c:cb:26:9b:2b:b5:09:6f:b1:cd:91:00:c3:f7:34:9f
isCa                 : false
isValid              : true
```

However if you check the xml file you will get #text instead of the read data

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <MS>
      <Obj N="NsxManagerCertificate" RefId="1">
        <TN RefId="1">
          <T>System.Xml.XmlElement</T>
          <T>System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode</T>
          <T>System.Xml.XmlNode</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <IE>
          <Obj RefId="2">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="3">
                <TN RefId="2">
                  <T>System.Xml.XmlText</T>
                  <T>System.Xml.XmlCharacterData</T>
                  <T>System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode</T>
                  <T>System.Xml.XmlNode</T>
                  <T>System.Object</T>
                </TN>
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="4">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="5">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="6">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="7">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">3</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="8">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="9">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">49044a14</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="10">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="11">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">SHA256WITHRSA</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="12">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="13">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">0b 5d c7 cb ab 58 0d 9a ff 03 e9 0a e5 91 61 64 16 22 c7 c2 21 28 50 f2 ad 02 21 e9 48 4e f6 72 d3 91 f1 19 3e 3e 25 3a fd 28 ab 81 e2 6c d1 35 51 dc 13 c4 22 f3 cb 53 db 6d c5 0c fe ff 6b 0b cd fc 17 d2 d5 bd d0 b8 13 e2 53 e7 2b 1e 8a 84 ee 54 f4 dc b3 7d 1a 70 4b 71 12 42 6b 2c b5 1c 65 85 94 9d f5 00 7c 28 0f 6f 5b 15 b4 fe 67 e2 fa 4c 10 6c 31 a4 4a df 48 f2 c1 a1 66 e5 d2 0a 80 3e f4 02 c3 75 95 4c e0 d8 5b 90 74 9a 85 56 b4 f2 9e 2b c3 c7 f4 71 fa 43 b2 c2 1e 65 a6 0b 8b eb fc 39 77 bd 04 39 b4 99 64 81 d5 0d 81 88 a9 33 63 72 9f a4 b3 d7 c5 33 97 14 d5 be 3f 8e a9 de fd 0f 1c 3d 63 fd 0c ff e2 12 03 59 53 f1 a5 96 cb a6 03 23 4b ef 71 38 0e 96 fb 85 4d 4c a8 8b 48 50 a6 e0 ff c6 f9 25 b5 8f d4 d2 0c 82 4c ff 9f e3 ef 9a e9 44 57 c5 3c 06 b8 b5 f9 2e</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="14">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="15">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">1527008785000</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="16">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="17">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">1842368785000</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="18">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="19">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="20">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="21">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="22">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="23">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">RSA</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="24">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="25">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">2048</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="26">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="27">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">00 a5 7d 07 71 38 f5 39 fd 64 61 15 4a a6 ec 2a 51 d6 1b 49 08 6b 37 74 ae 8e 5e 21 db a5 48 73 e1 45 5b 02 5c 60 0c 9c 49 77 45 a4 43 f9 2b 05 a8 02 3b cb e7 17 89 18 79 38 5b a0 1d 77 3b c3 90 3d 39 8c 5e 25 90 80 d0 a0 df f1 32 52 4c 46 8b 86 1f 67 5b 1a ee 56 3e d0 bf cc 45 5d 7a b8 f7 65 d0 4b 92 94 9f 1f 22 0d ae a6 d2 cb e6 00 92 f6 41 1b 52 4b 1d ba dc 24 04 e3 f5 2c c5 26 f0 d0 2c 02 b4 6b c2 f0 12 e7 20 c5 fe 4f d2 8f 12 8d 2d 2c 3e 8a cb 63 f7 d9 37 0c fd 43 53 e3 14 cd 51 b5 68 0d e7 59 ad a3 8e 28 53 72 d1 97 65 f2 bf fb 6c 78 63 d8 57 fe 8f 6b 89 53 ac a2 0c 0d 83 bd be d5 14 7b 4c cf 15 22 60 17 1e 1f f7 28 7f 64 ac 28 a7 26 d3 bc c7 5a c0 42 e6 34 00 57 62 99 6a 0c 4c 54 a4 6e b7 b8 73 43 1d 65 f7 b8 cd fc 99 75 8c 49 f1 0f 72 70 1b 4c 47 0e 7b</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="28">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="29">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">10001</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="30">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="31">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">05:69:31:14:c9:41:0d:30:d6:52:e6:83:e8:6a:56:ad:1e:84:a5:37</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="32">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="33">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">1c:cb:26:9b:2b:b5:09:6f:b1:cd:91:00:c3:f7:34:9f</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="34">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="35">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">false</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
          <Obj RefId="36">
            <TNRef RefId="1" />
            <IE>
              <Obj RefId="37">
                <TNRef RefId="2" />
                <ToString>#text</ToString>
              </Obj>
            </IE>
            <Props>
              <S N="#text">true</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
        </IE>
        <Props>
          <S N="subjectCn">CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss</S>
          <S N="issuerCn">CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss</S>
          <S N="version">3</S>
          <S N="serialNumber">49044a14</S>
          <S N="signatureAlgo">SHA256WITHRSA</S>
          <S N="signature">0b 5d c7 cb ab 58 0d 9a ff 03 e9 0a e5 91 61 64 16 22 c7 c2 21 28 50 f2 ad 02 21 e9 48 4e f6 72 d3 91 f1 19 3e 3e 25 3a fd 28 ab 81 e2 6c d1 35 51 dc 13 c4 22 f3 cb 53 db 6d c5 0c fe ff 6b 0b cd fc 17 d2 d5 bd d0 b8 13 e2 53 e7 2b 1e 8a 84 ee 54 f4 dc b3 7d 1a 70 4b 71 12 42 6b 2c b5 1c 65 85 94 9d f5 00 7c 28 0f 6f 5b 15 b4 fe 67 e2 fa 4c 10 6c 31 a4 4a df 48 f2 c1 a1 66 e5 d2 0a 80 3e f4 02 c3 75 95 4c e0 d8 5b 90 74 9a 85 56 b4 f2 9e 2b c3 c7 f4 71 fa 43 b2 c2 1e 65 a6 0b 8b eb fc 39 77 bd 04 39 b4 99 64 81 d5 0d 81 88 a9 33 63 72 9f a4 b3 d7 c5 33 97 14 d5 be 3f 8e a9 de fd 0f 1c 3d 63 fd 0c ff e2 12 03 59 53 f1 a5 96 cb a6 03 23 4b ef 71 38 0e 96 fb 85 4d 4c a8 8b 48 50 a6 e0 ff c6 f9 25 b5 8f d4 d2 0c 82 4c ff 9f e3 ef 9a e9 44 57 c5 3c 06 b8 b5 f9 2e</S>
          <S N="notBefore">1527008785000</S>
          <S N="notAfter">1842368785000</S>
          <S N="issuer">CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US</S>
          <S N="subject">CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US</S>
          <S N="publicKeyAlgo">RSA</S>
          <S N="publicKeyLength">2048</S>
          <S N="rsaPublicKeyModulus">00 a5 7d 07 71 38 f5 39 fd 64 61 15 4a a6 ec 2a 51 d6 1b 49 08 6b 37 74 ae 8e 5e 21 db a5 48 73 e1 45 5b 02 5c 60 0c 9c 49 77 45 a4 43 f9 2b 05 a8 02 3b cb e7 17 89 18 79 38 5b a0 1d 77 3b c3 90 3d 39 8c 5e 25 90 80 d0 a0 df f1 32 52 4c 46 8b 86 1f 67 5b 1a ee 56 3e d0 bf cc 45 5d 7a b8 f7 65 d0 4b 92 94 9f 1f 22 0d ae a6 d2 cb e6 00 92 f6 41 1b 52 4b 1d ba dc 24 04 e3 f5 2c c5 26 f0 d0 2c 02 b4 6b c2 f0 12 e7 20 c5 fe 4f d2 8f 12 8d 2d 2c 3e 8a cb 63 f7 d9 37 0c fd 43 53 e3 14 cd 51 b5 68 0d e7 59 ad a3 8e 28 53 72 d1 97 65 f2 bf fb 6c 78 63 d8 57 fe 8f 6b 89 53 ac a2 0c 0d 83 bd be d5 14 7b 4c cf 15 22 60 17 1e 1f f7 28 7f 64 ac 28 a7 26 d3 bc c7 5a c0 42 e6 34 00 57 62 99 6a 0c 4c 54 a4 6e b7 b8 73 43 1d 65 f7 b8 cd fc 99 75 8c 49 f1 0f 72 70 1b 4c 47 0e 7b</S>
          <S N="rsaPublicKeyExponent">10001</S>
          <S N="sha1Hash">05:69:31:14:c9:41:0d:30:d6:52:e6:83:e8:6a:56:ad:1e:84:a5:37</S>
          <S N="md5Hash">1c:cb:26:9b:2b:b5:09:6f:b1:cd:91:00:c3:f7:34:9f</S>
          <S N="isCa">false</S>
          <S N="isValid">true</S>
        </Props>
      </Obj>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

Then use the Import-Clixml to get the data and you will find the values are #text (I think this is reading only the #text values in each object)

```
C:\Users\Administrator> $TestImport = Import-Clixml -Path E:\TestDump.xml

 C:\Users\Administrator> $TestImport

NsxManagerCertificate          
---------------------          
{#text, #text, #text, #text...}



 C:\Users\Administrator> $TestImport.NsxManagerCertificate
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
#text
```

After a number of checks, I was able to work around it and I think I was able to identify the main issue here. the $NsxManagerCertificate object is of type XmlElement

C:\Users\Administrator> $NsxManagerCertificate.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    XmlElement                               System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode

If i recreate it in a new PSCustomObject as below and then export it and then import it it wroks like a charm.

```
$NsxsubjectCn = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.subjectCn
$NsxissuerCn = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.issuerCn
$Nsxversion = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.version
$NsxserialNumber = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.serialNumber
$NsxsignatureAlgo = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.signatureAlgo
$Nsxsignature = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.signature
$NsxnotBefore = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.notBefore
$NsxnotAfter = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.notAfter
$Nsxissuer = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.issuer
$Nsxsubject = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.subject
$NsxpublicKeyAlgo = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.publicKeyAlgo
$NsxpublicKeyLength = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.publicKeyLength
$NsxrsaPublicKeyModulus = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.rsaPublicKeyModulus
$NsxrsaPublicKeyExponent = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.rsaPublicKeyExponent
$Nsxsha1Hash = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.sha1Hash
$Nsxmd5Hash = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.md5Hash
$NsxisCa = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.isCa
$NsxisValid = $NsxManagerCertificateGet.isValid

$NsxManagerCertificate = [PSCustomObject] @{
    subjectCn = $NsxsubjectCn
    issuerCn = $NsxissuerCn
    version = $Nsxversion
    serialNumber = $NsxserialNumber
    signatureAlgo = $NsxsignatureAlgo
    signature = $Nsxsignature
    notBefore = $NsxnotBefore
    notAfter = $NsxnotAfter
    issuer = $Nsxissuer
    subject = $Nsxsubject
    publicKeyAlgo = $NsxpublicKeyAlgo
    publicKeyLength = $NsxpublicKeyLength
    rsaPublicKeyModulus = $NsxrsaPublicKeyModulus
    rsaPublicKeyExponent = $NsxrsaPublicKeyExponent
    sha1Hash = $Nsxsha1Hash
    md5Hash = $Nsxmd5Hash
    isCa = $NsxisCa
    isValid = $NsxisValid
}

C:\Users\Administrator> Export-Clixml -InputObject $NsxManagerCertificate -Path E:\TestExport.xml

 C:\Users\Administrator> $CheckImportTest = Import-Clixml -Path E:\TestExport.xml

 C:\Users\Administrator> $CheckImportTest


subjectCn            : CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss
issuerCn             : CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss
version              : 3
serialNumber         : 49044a14
signatureAlgo        : SHA256WITHRSA
signature            : 0b 5d c7 cb ab 58 0d 9a ff 03 e9 0a e5 91 61 64 16 22 c7 c2 21 28 50 f2 ad 02 21 e9 48 4e f6 72 d3 91 f1 19 3e 3e 25 3a fd 28 ab 81 e2 6c d1 35 51 dc 13 c4 22 f3 cb 53 db 6d c5 0c fe ff 6b 0b cd fc 17 d2 d5 bd d0 b8 13 e2 
                       53 e7 2b 1e 8a 84 ee 54 f4 dc b3 7d 1a 70 4b 71 12 42 6b 2c b5 1c 65 85 94 9d f5 00 7c 28 0f 6f 5b 15 b4 fe 67 e2 fa 4c 10 6c 31 a4 4a df 48 f2 c1 a1 66 e5 d2 0a 80 3e f4 02 c3 75 95 4c e0 d8 5b 90 74 9a 85 56 b4 f2 9e 2b 
                       c3 c7 f4 71 fa 43 b2 c2 1e 65 a6 0b 8b eb fc 39 77 bd 04 39 b4 99 64 81 d5 0d 81 88 a9 33 63 72 9f a4 b3 d7 c5 33 97 14 d5 be 3f 8e a9 de fd 0f 1c 3d 63 fd 0c ff e2 12 03 59 53 f1 a5 96 cb a6 03 23 4b ef 71 38 0e 96 fb 85 
                       4d 4c a8 8b 48 50 a6 e0 ff c6 f9 25 b5 8f d4 d2 0c 82 4c ff 9f e3 ef 9a e9 44 57 c5 3c 06 b8 b5 f9 2e
notBefore            : 1527008785000
notAfter             : 1842368785000
issuer               : CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
subject              : CN=CGSR-NSX.nfv.gss,OU=NSX,O=VMware Inc.,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
publicKeyAlgo        : RSA
publicKeyLength      : 2048
rsaPublicKeyModulus  : 00 a5 7d 07 71 38 f5 39 fd 64 61 15 4a a6 ec 2a 51 d6 1b 49 08 6b 37 74 ae 8e 5e 21 db a5 48 73 e1 45 5b 02 5c 60 0c 9c 49 77 45 a4 43 f9 2b 05 a8 02 3b cb e7 17 89 18 79 38 5b a0 1d 77 3b c3 90 3d 39 8c 5e 25 90 80 d0 a0 
                       df f1 32 52 4c 46 8b 86 1f 67 5b 1a ee 56 3e d0 bf cc 45 5d 7a b8 f7 65 d0 4b 92 94 9f 1f 22 0d ae a6 d2 cb e6 00 92 f6 41 1b 52 4b 1d ba dc 24 04 e3 f5 2c c5 26 f0 d0 2c 02 b4 6b c2 f0 12 e7 20 c5 fe 4f d2 8f 12 8d 2d 2c 
                       3e 8a cb 63 f7 d9 37 0c fd 43 53 e3 14 cd 51 b5 68 0d e7 59 ad a3 8e 28 53 72 d1 97 65 f2 bf fb 6c 78 63 d8 57 fe 8f 6b 89 53 ac a2 0c 0d 83 bd be d5 14 7b 4c cf 15 22 60 17 1e 1f f7 28 7f 64 ac 28 a7 26 d3 bc c7 5a c0 42 
                       e6 34 00 57 62 99 6a 0c 4c 54 a4 6e b7 b8 73 43 1d 65 f7 b8 cd fc 99 75 8c 49 f1 0f 72 70 1b 4c 47 0e 7b
rsaPublicKeyExponent : 10001
sha1Hash             : 05:69:31:14:c9:41:0d:30:d6:52:e6:83:e8:6a:56:ad:1e:84:a5:37
md5Hash              : 1c:cb:26:9b:2b:b5:09:6f:b1:cd:91:00:c3:f7:34:9f
isCa                 : false
isValid              : true

$CheckImportTest.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                  
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

The main question would be: Is there an easier way to convert an XmlElement type of object into PSCustomObject

Comment: IIRC the `-Depth` parameter of Export-Clixml is by default set to two. Increase it and retry.

Comment: Hi LotPings, thanks for the help. I tried the -Depth but it did not help, i have did a number of tests and the only thing that works is when i re-create the object